# How can I remove a dead bolt?

Tags: doors, lock

I'm trying to remove a 16 yr. old Titan Dead Bolt. I have it disassembled but cannot get it out of the door. There is no strike plate on the door that I can remove. There is only a brass ring that the bolt goes through on the door side. How do I get the old mechanism out?

Comment: This is one of those questions where a picture can help immensely.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, it is probably just a pressure fit. You should be able to pry it so it comes straight out the edge of the door from where the cylinder sits. This picture is just of a normal doorknob, but same principle applies.

[image]

Comment: That's what it looks like...thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Yep, run steel drift pin through, pull both sides towards you, latch pops out.